# Displaying a string of of characters from an array of ascii hex values assembly language

Tags: assembly, ascii, tasm

Okay I'm working on assembly for Intel based computers homework, professor has us work in 16 bits for the sake of simplicity. The assignment is to take a number entered by the user and convert it into an integer from ASCII and then store that integer in an array. I've got this part working fine. We are then to take the integers out of the array and convert them back into ASCII and print them to the screen. This is also working okay for the most part, until I print.

I use tasm and when i trace through my code with the debugger it displays the numbers that it should but they are surrounded by a lot of empty space and some strange characters. then when i just try to run the code in the command prompt all i get is some really messed up characters and then it seems to crash.

EDIT: the printing now works fine, but ive realized that the rest is buggier than i thought. for instance if i type any number lower than 2559 it seems to work just fine, but if i type any number 2560 or above i get a divide by zero error. any help with this would be appreciated.

How the code is supposed to work
it prompts you for a number (the number should be able to be any unsigned 16bit integer)
you type a number and press enter
type another number press enter
type another number press enter (should be able to enter up to 10 numbers in this way)
when you're done entering numbers type type the minus sign "-"
it should then repeat back to you the numbers you typed

heres my code:

```
.MODEL small

.STACK 200h
CR EQU 13
LF EQU 10

.DATA
;variables used by InputNumber procedure
BinaryValue dw 0
CharacterCount dw 0
Index dw 0
Multiplier dw 1
InputString db 7 dup (0)
prompt2 db 'Enter A Number:', '$'


;variables used by LoadArray prcedure
prompt1 db 'You may enter up to 10 positive integers then enter a -1', CR, LF,  '$'
userFlag db 0
numberArray dw 10 dup (0)
numArraySize dw 0

;variables for PrintArray
prompt3 db 'Array data is:', '$'
numSize dw 0

.CODE
Main proc
    MOV ax, @data
    MOV ds, ax
    CALL LoadArray
    CALL PrintArray
    MOV ax, 4c00h
    INT 21h
Main endp





LoadArray proc
    ; informs the user to enter numbers then enter a -1
    MOV ah, 09h
    MOV dx, offset prompt1
    INT 21h

    Mov di, 0
    While1:
        Mov BinaryValue, 0
        Mov CharacterCount, 0
        Mov Index, 0
        Mov Multiplier, 1
        Call InputNumber
        Cmp userFlag, 0
        Jne endWhile1
        Mov bx, BinaryValue
        Mov numberArray[di], bx
        Inc di
        Inc di
        jmp While1
    endWhile1:
    Mov numArraySize, di
    RET
LoadArray endp





InputNumber proc
    MOV ah, 09h
    MOV dx, offset prompt2
    INT 21h

    ;Get character from keyboard
    Mov ah, 01h
    Int 21h

    ;while that character is not the enter key keep getting keys from the keyboard
    Mov si, CharacterCount
    while2:
        Cmp al, 0Dh
        Je endWhile2
        Cmp al, 2Dh
        Je endOfProc
        Mov InputString[si], al
        Inc si
        Mov ah, 01h
        Int 21h
        jmp while2
    endWhile2:
    Mov CharacterCount, si

    ;initializing multiplier and index to the values needed
    Mov Multiplier, 1
    Dec si
    Mov Index, si

    ;loop through InputString array pulling out each character, convert it by removing its ascii bits and muliplying it by its place value  
    Mov cx, CharacterCount
    Mov CharacterCount, 0
    convertLoop:
        Mov al, InputString[si]
        And ax, 0Fh
        Mul Multiplier
        Add BinaryValue, ax
        Mov ax, 10
        Mul Multiplier
        Mov Multiplier, ax
        Dec si
        Loop convertLoop
    RET
endOfProc:
    Mov userFlag, 1
    RET
InputNumber endp




PrintArray proc
    MOV ah, 09h
    MOV dx, offset prompt3
    INT 21h

    Mov si, 0
    doWhile1:
        Mov bx, numberArray[si]
        Mov BinaryValue, bx
        call DisplayNumber
        Inc si
        Inc si
        Cmp si, numArraySize
        jb doWhile1
    RET
PrintArray endp




DisplayNumber proc
    Mov ax, BinaryValue
    ;determine size of the number in BinaryValue
    loop1:
        Mov bl, 10
        Div bl
        cmp al, 0 
        je end1
        Inc numSize
        Mov ah, 0
        jmp loop1
    end1:
    Inc numSize
    Mov di, numSize
    Mov InputString[di], '$'
    dec di
    Mov ax, 0
    Mov ax, BinaryValue
    while3:
        cmp ax, 10
        jb endWhile3
        Div bl
        Or ah, 30h
        Mov InputString[di], ah
        Mov ah, 0
        dec di
        jmp While3
    endWhile3:
    Or al, 30h
    Mov InputString[di], al

    ;print the ascii characters stored in InputString to the screen
    Mov dx, word ptr InputString[di]
    Mov ah, 09h
    Int 21h
    Ret
DisplayNumber endp
end main
```

I'll be working on this till its working since i'll need it for later assignments. Any help would be really appreciated. even if its a suggestion on how to clean up the code or make it better or more readable (including style).

Comment: `Mov dx, word ptr InputString[di]` doesn't look right to me. Try `lea` there.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot with the printing. it now properly displays the numbers but now I realize that rest of it isnt working quite as well as i thought.

Comment: My assembly is a bit rusty, but are you sure it should be "numberArray dw 10 dup (0)" and not "numberArray dw 0 dup (10)"?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code, and paid attention only to this part of your question:

> EDIT: the printing now works fine, but ive realized that the rest is buggier than i thought. for instance if i type any number lower than 2559 it seems to work just fine, but if i type any number 2560 or above i get a divide by zero error. any help with this would be appreciated.

The problem is in `DisplayNumber` here:

```
Mov ax, BinaryValue
;determine size of the number in BinaryValue
loop1:
    Mov bl, 10
    Div bl
    cmp al, 0 
    je end1
```

`Div bl` is an 8-bit divide by a register, so the source is `ax`. It does the division, and puts the result in `al` and the remainder in `ah` - as the following statement `cmp al,0` tests for.

The problem is if the result of the division won't fit into `al` - which is exactly what happens when `BinaryValue` is 2560 or larger: `2560 / 10 = 256`, which won't fit into `al`. So the processor raises a `Divide` exception - colloquially called `Division by zero` since that's the easiest way to get it, but it's raised in other situations as well.